# SSRS text box formatting depending on if column IS NOT NULL

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, formatting

I have a tablix with a percentage as the data. I want to format that box based on the results in other columns (inc_number, crq_number, wlg_number). If any of them have a value of IS NOT NULL make them green if not make it red.

I was thinking along the lines of

```
=IIF((ISNOTHING(Fields!inc_number)),"Red","green")
OR IIF((ISNOTHING(Fields!crq_number)),"Red","green")
OR IIF((ISNOTHING(Fields!wlg_number)),"Red","green")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `AND`?

```
=iif(isnothing(Fields!inc_number) 
         and isnothing(Fields!crq_number) 
         and isnothing(Fields!wlg_number),
     "Red",
     "Green")
```

Comment: No that doesn't seem to work. The fields above aren't in the actual report but the colour of the percentage cell shown is dependent on their values

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=Switch(
  ISNOTHING(Fields!inc_number.Value) OR Fields!inc_number.Value = "","Red",
  ISNOTHING(Fields!crq_number.Value) OR Fields!crq_number.Value = "","Red",
  ISNOTHING(Fields!wlg_number.Value) OR Fields!wlg_number.Value = "","Red",
  true,"Green"
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this just turns the whole report green

Comment: @DeanFlaherty, I've updated the expression, try it again.

Comment: @DeanFlaherty, the expression do what you need accroding to the question. could you add the data returned by your dataset in order to see what is happening?